# Debugging a Django app on a server running FCGI

Tags: django, debugging, fastcgi

I developed my Django app on my local machine, however when I uploaded it to my server (DreamHost, running FCGI) I ran into some problems.

How can I debug Django on my DreamHost server that's running FCGI?

Comment: What problems did you encounter?
What sort of debug do you need?

Comment: I got my problem solved. I just need to reinstall python as they had move me to a different server and something went awry.

Comment: Please consider adding your fix as an answer to help others.

Comment: @Jacinda, unfortunately, I don't have an answer on how to debug django from a fcgi server, so not sure how to answer it. My problem was caused by the python version.